# Is there any official (or semi-official) clarification on how often Psychic Virtuoso allows a character to use occult skill unlocks?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, skills, errata, occult-magic

The description of the [Psychic Virtuoso](https://aonprd.com/FeatDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Psychic%20Virtuoso) feat from *Occult Adventures* states "You can use all of your occult skill unlocks more often and you are more talented at using them."  However, the Benefit section only lists a bonus for using them, nothing about using them more often.  I cannot find any errata or clarification for this feat indicating either it doesn't actually let you use occult skill unlocks more often or, if it does, how often it allows a character to use them.

Comment: As written this is a “designer intent” question, which is off topic. Voting to close. The question should be rephrased to ask about rules, not rules designers.

Comment: I don't think this is designer intent per se. It looks like Cadrac has observed what appears to be a contradiction within the rules text and is wondering if there exists a resolution to that contradiction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### The feats description appears to be in error.

Nothing in the actual text of the feat gives you additional uses of the psychic skill unlocks. The full text of the feats effect is:

> **Benefit:** You gain a +2 bonus on checks to use occult skill unlocks. If you have more than 10 ranks in the base skill, this bonus increases to +4. This bonus doesn’t apply on other checks using the base skills—only on checks for occult skill unlocks.

For using the unlocks more often, you'll want the feat Psychic Maestro

**Psychic Maestro**

> You can use two occult skill unlocks more often.
>
> **Prerequisite:** Psychic Sensitivity or the ability to cast psychic spells.
>
> **Benefit:** Choose two occult skill unlocks. You can use each of those one additional time per day (or per week, in the case of automatic writing). You must have at least 1 rank in the skills associated with the chosen occult skill unlocks.

It's *possible* that at some point in the design process, these were both a single feat, and were split at some point, and the description not getting fixed could have been an oversight, hence the description not matching the feats effects, but that's just a guess at best.